# Show that there exists no positive continuous function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ that satisfies the following conditions:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Show that there exists no positive continuous function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ that satisfies the following conditions:

$\int_a^bf(t)dt=1$,

$\int_a^btf(t)dt=\alpha$,

$\int_a^bt^2f(t)dt=\alpha^2$

where $\alpha$ is a prescribed number.

Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the Cauchy—Schwarz inequality: 
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha&=\int_a^btf(t)dt\\
&=\int_a^b t\sqrt{f(t)}\sqrt{f(t)}\\
&\le(\int_a^bt^2f(t)dt.\int_a^bf(t)dt)^\frac12\\
&=(\alpha^2)^\frac12=\alpha
\end{align}
$$ 
So, we must have a chain of equalities. For equality to hold in the Cauchy—Schwarz Inequality, we must have: $t\sqrt{f(t)}=c\sqrt{f(t)}$ for some constant $c$, and from here: $\sqrt{f(t)}\equiv 0$, which contradicts: $$\int_a^bf(t)=1$$ Thus, no such function $f$ can exist.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

- find a polynomial $X^2 - rX+s$ of which $\alpha$ is a root and which stays non-negative on $[a,b]$.
- Consider $$0 = \alpha^2 - r\alpha+s = \int_a^b (t^2f(t)-rtf(t)+sf(t))dt
  = \int_a^b (t^2-rt+s)f(t)dt $$
- Conclude that the integrand is zero on $[a,b]$, being continuous.

Comment: What if $\alpha \in (a,b)$?

Comment: You can still have a non-negative degree-2 polynomial -- it'll just have one root there (so will not be positive, only non-negative).

Comment: Ah, of course. Never mind.